# PubNub GCM notifications not working on Android 5.0 and above

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-5.0-lollipop, pubnub

I am trying to work with `GCM` push notifications using `PubNub` as a gateway.
The notifications are delivered perfectly on android devices with OS version < 5.0 but with 5.0 devices the `GCM` listener service is never called (both on WiFi and cellular), also I am not getting any `SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE` error and based on the output the registration token is passed successfully to `PubNub`.

```
public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {

    public RegistrationIntentService() {
        super("");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        try {
            // In the (unlikely) event that multiple refresh operations occur simultaneously,
            // ensure that they are processed sequentially.
            synchronized ("Reg Service") {
        try {
            PNConfiguration.registration_Token = getRegistrationToken();
            Log.d("Token",PNConfiguration.registration_Token);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        sendRegistrationToServer();
                sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(PNConfiguration.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, true).apply();
                // [END register_for_gcm]
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Reg Service", "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
            // If an exception happens while fetching the new token or updating our registration data
            // on a third-party server, this ensures that we'll attempt the update at a later time.
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(PNConfiguration.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false).apply();
        }
        // Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress indicator can be hidden.
        Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(PNConfiguration.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);

    }

    public String getRegistrationToken() throws IOException {

        InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
        String token = instanceID.getToken(PNConfiguration.project_sender_id,
                GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);

        return token;
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer() {
        Log.d("Came here",PNConfiguration.registration_Token);
        Log.d("channel",PNConfiguration.user_channel_name);
        PNConfiguration.PUBNUB.enablePushNotificationsOnChannel(PNConfiguration.user_channel_name, PNConfiguration.registration_Token, new
                Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void successCallback(String channel, Object message) {
                        super.successCallback(channel, message);
                        Log.d("Sent token to Pubnub", PNConfiguration.registration_Token);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error) {
                        super.errorCallback(channel, error);
                        Log.d("Unsucessful Send token ", error.toString());

                    }
                });
    }
}
```

My manifest

```
<service android:name=".GCMPushNotifications.RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
</service>

<service android:name=".GCMPushNotifications.GCMListenerService"
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service android:name=".GCMPushNotifications.PNInstanceIDListenerService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
    </intent-filter></service>
<receiver
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I have the 'classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1' in my top level gradle and

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.+'
```

in my app level gradle.

Inside onCreate of my mainActivity

```
mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
                    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            boolean sentToken = sharedPreferences
                    .getBoolean(PNConfiguration.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false);
            if (sentToken) {

                Log.d("Info sent","");
            } else {
                Log.d("error sending token","");
            }
        }
    };
    Log.d("value of play services",checkPlayServices()+"");
    if (checkPlayServices()) {
        // Start IntentService to register this application with GCM.
        Log.d("ABC","Starting service");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
        intent.setPackage("com.livongo.lvmobility.GCMPushNotifications.RegistrationIntentService");
        startService(intent);
    }
```

Please help me understand if I am missing something here.Any help is appreciated

Comment: Just wanted to add to the answer, it wasn't an OS issue after all, the GCMlistenerService never started on my device when i was trying to send a message from another device, but I used a plugin ( postman) to check my GCM API and sending a message from there started the service and since then ( since the service has started once and for all) the notifications are working seamlessly. I am still not sure why this unreliability is there.

Answer (score 0):

PubNub does not actually deliver the push notification. When you send a Push Notification via publishing to a channel we forward that push to the appropriate Push vendor (we are the gateway).

This sounds like it has more to do with android 5.0.

do you have the proper permissions in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<permission
    android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```